# Login request invalid

Tags: c#, pastebin

When i try to get api_user_key using this code, api_dev_key,api_user_login and api_user_password replaced, but I am not sure, that it is correct;

```
WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("http://pastebin.com/api/api_login.php");
req.Method = "POST";
req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";              
byte[] Bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("api_dev_key=12345678901234567890012345678901&api_user_login=lll&api_user_password=lll");
req.ContentLength = Bytes.Length;
Stream os = req.GetRequestStream();
os.Write(Bytes, 0, Bytes.Length);
os.Close();
WebResponse resq = req.GetResponse();
StreamReader ss = new StreamReader(resq.GetResponseStream());
return ss.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: And... i created post with my correct dev key, but when i try to login, i have error. :(

Comment: Have you tried manually logging in with those credentials?

Comment: Yes, i am trying to login using site and this form:http://pastebin.com/api/api_user_key.html
And all sucess. But when i try to login using programm, i get "invalid api_dev_key" error. And i CAN create post, using this key. By guest.

Comment: *"invalid post parameters" in place of "invalid api_dev_key", and not only using this key, using... ex "api_dev_key=12345678901234567890012345678901&api_option=post&api_post_code=asdasda"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass `api_user_name` (not `api_user_login`)